# How is gold (the element) gold (the color)?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, material-science, metals

This question is related to the inquiry here:
[What enables protons to give new properties to an atom every time one is added?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160548/)

and here: [What causes atoms to have their specific colors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80919/)

In general, assume you are given an input wavelength(s) of electromagnetic radiation, and a set of neutrons, protons, and electrons in a certain state (likely an atom). Is there a function that will map these values to the wavelength(s) of electromagnetic radiation after it has become incident with the set of neutrons, protons, and electrons?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72368/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Zroach - Johannes' excellent answer to that question provides the answer to your question.